# PHP Check if 2 variables are the same, like a test

Tags: php, variables

I need help to check if variables (from a database) are the same, like a test.
First I was using just "==", but I saw this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php , and now I'm using "===". But it still doesn't work.

My code:

```
    $uids = array();
    $trues = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      array_push($uids, $row['UID']);
    } while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      array_push($uids, $row1['UID']);
    } while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
      array_push($uids, $row2['UID']);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($uids); $i++) {
      $r = 0;
      if ($row['question1'] === $row['uAnswer1']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question2'] === $row['uAnswer2']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question3'] === $row['uAnswer3']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question4'] === $row['uAnswer4']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question5'] === $row['uAnswer5']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question6'] === $row['uAnswer6']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question7'] === $row['uAnswer7']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question8'] === $row['uAnswer8']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question9'] === $row['uAnswer9']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
          $r = $r;
      } if ($row['question10'] === $row['uAnswer10']) {
        $r++;
      } else {
        $r = $r;
      }
      array_push($trues, $r);
      echo $uids[$i] . " [" . $r . "]<br>";
    }
    print_r($trues);
  }
```

What the result is: https://hastebin.com/uxitoyoyib.php

So it actually says everything is right, but I know that it isn't. Can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Code goes in the post. Please, take the [tour] and read the [ask] guide.

Answer (score 1):

Compare variables like

```
if ( strtolower(trim($row['question5'])) === strtolower(trim($row['uAnswer5'])) )
```

Remove spaces if added with strings, convert the string in lowercase to the exact match of both strings.

Comment: What does trim()? If I don't understand the the php.net documentation.

And I don't want to use strtolower because of the test, if someone typed capital letters it should be fault.

Comment: trim() will remove unnecessary spaces from start and end positions, and lowercase() used to convert both strings in the same format to match exact value, if you will try to match lowercase value to uppercase value with === operator it will never give you correct match answer. if you want to check for both strings identical then you should convert strings in the same format and then match.

Comment: But if a uppercase character isn't the good answer? You'll say something is right but it isn't..?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  if ($row['question4'] == $row['uAnswer4']) {
        //do something
        }
```

and try to print your 2 variable.

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\request.php on line 1295`


And the colors in my editor are doing weird...

Comment: you write use ?

Comment: Oh I read it fault. Sorry for that, but if you use "==" you'll check if the type is the same, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) or [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) functions or the `===` operator.